# simplexml_load_string strange parsing and object conversion

Tags: php

Given the following structure as XML:

```
<USERS COUNT="3" >
    <USER FIRST_NAME="asdsd" ROLEID="10" EMAIL="blub2@fasel.com" STATUS="ACTIVE" LAST_NAME="asda" USERID="100" >
        <LOCATION LOCATIONID="9" NAME="Test Users" SORT_ORDER="0" ></LOCATION>
    </USER>
    <USER FIRST_NAME="gffgh" ROLEID="10" EMAIL="blub@fasel.de" STATUS="ACTIVE" LAST_NAME="fghfgh" USERID="99" >
        <LOCATION LOCATIONID="9" NAME="Test Users" SORT_ORDER="0" ></LOCATION>
    </USER>
    <USER FIRST_NAME="Hilmi" ROLEID="8" EMAIL="xxx@xxx.com" STATUS="ACITVE" LAST_NAME="xxx" USERID="98" >
        <LOCATION LOCATIONID="9" NAME="Test Users" SORT_ORDER="0" ></LOCATION>
    </USER>
</USERS>
```

this line

```
simplexml_load_string($data, 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA);
```

results in the following object:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(    
    [USERS] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
                (
                    [COUNT] => 3
                )

            [USER] => Array
                (
                    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [@attributes] => Array
                                (
                                    [FIRST_NAME] => asdsd
                                    [ROLEID] => 10
                                    [EMAIL] => blub2@fasel.com
                                    [STATUS] => ACTIVE
                                    [LAST_NAME] => asda
                                    [USERID] => 100
                                )

                            [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [@attributes] => Array
                                        (
                                            [LOCATIONID] => 9
                                            [NAME] => Test Users
                                            [SORT_ORDER] => 0
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [@attributes] => Array
                                (
                                    [FIRST_NAME] => gffgh
                                    [ROLEID] => 10
                                    [EMAIL] => blub@fasel.de
                                    [STATUS] => ACTIVE
                                    [LAST_NAME] => fghfgh
                                    [USERID] => 99
                                )

                            [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [@attributes] => Array
                                        (
                                            [LOCATIONID] => 9
                                            [NAME] => Test Users
                                            [SORT_ORDER] => 0
                                        )
                                )
                        )

                    [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [@attributes] => Array
                                (
                                    [FIRST_NAME] => Hilmi
                                    [ROLEID] => 8
                                    [EMAIL] => xxx@xxx.com
                                    [STATUS] => ACITVE
                                    [LAST_NAME] => Hilmiev
                                    [USERID] => 98
                                )

                            [LOCATION] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [@attributes] => Array
                                        (
                                            [LOCATIONID] => 9
                                            [NAME] => Test Users
                                            [SORT_ORDER] => 0
                                        )
                               )
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

The `<LOCATION>` sub elements #1 and #2 are converted as `[0]` and `[1]` and the last (and always only the last one) is converted as `[LOCATION]`

PHP Version 5.5.14

I would have expected something like

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(    
    [USERS] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
                ...

            [USER] => Array
                (
                    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [@attributes] => Array
                                (
                                    ...
                                )

                            [LOCATION] => SimpleXMLElement Object
```

for all of the sub elements.

Does anyone have a explanation for that?

Comment: Do you get the same result if you use `simplexml_load_string($data)` ? Also, if you're trying to access a key/value of one of the nested array elements, you will want to cast it first.  For example `(String) $obj->element`

Comment: Did the change, absolutely no difference.

Comment: At least this PHP 'fiddle' shows expected output http://www.tehplayground.com/#UjciCrVMP , admittedly running a different PHP version.

Comment: @Thernys thanks for fiddling! Strange as this is a lower PHP version (5.3) ...?

Comment: Just tested 5.5.9 and 5.3.17: 5.5.9 has the described behaviour on both ubuntu and SLES

Comment: By 'described' you mean unexpected? In the PHP 5.5.27 interactive shell I get expected output similar to the fiddle. How is your $data variable actually populated?

Comment: I copied your fiddle in to 5.5.9: erroneous output as in the question. Then I copied your fiddle in to 5.3.17: output as expected. So it's not about the data, as I made the test with your code.